# errors::unordered_map not declared and expected primary expression before int

Tags: c++, declaration, unordered-map

## compilation error:: unordered_map not declared in line 5

### expected primary expression before int in line 15:: "unordered_map (int,int) hashmap;"

at times the error is solved by using
"using namespace std"
but here it is still not being resolved

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int help(int n, unordered_map <int,int> hashmap)
{
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
   int n;
   cin>>n;
  unordered_map <int,int> hashmap;
   cout<<help(n,hashmap)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Missing semicolon after hashmap definition.

Comment: Are you saying the error *"unordered_map not declared"* only occurs when you don't have `using namespace std;`? Because your code as shown should be fine.

Comment: no it is still not resolved this time

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](https://godbolt.org/z/KFRz3U).

Comment: Make sure you compile in C++11 mode (at least).